# Chaining in basic calculator?

Tags: javascript

> My calculator can only operate on 2 numbers at a time. I am not sure how to chain more than 2 numbers with different operators before pressing =. Can anyone give a hint of how to do it? (below is my javascript code)
>
> Link codepen: https://codepen.io/cmtran/pen/LzmbLM?editors=1111

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    var testNumLength = function(number) {
        if (number.length > 9) {
            totaldiv.text(number.substr(number.length-9,9));
            if (number.length > 15) {
                number = "";
                totaldiv.text("Err");
            }
        } 
    };
      var entry = "";
    var current = ""; //after operator is entered
    var operator = "";
  var res = "";
    var totaldiv = $("#total");
    totaldiv.text("0");
  
  $("#numbers a").not("#clear,#clearall").click(function(){
    entry += $(this).text();//take the text of the numbers when clicked and append it to var entry
    //display input1 on screen
    totaldiv.html(entry);
    testNumLength(entry);
  })
  
  $("#clear,#clearall").click(function(){
    entry = "";
    if ($(this).attr("id") === "clearall"){
      current = "";
    }
    totaldiv.text("0");
    
  })
  
  $("#operators a").click(function(){
    //append operators to var operator
     operator = $(this).text();
    
      current = entry;
      entry = "";
   
    
    
    })
  
  $("#decimal").click(function(){
        //var numOfDecs = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<entry.length;i++){
            
            if (entry.indexOf(".")== -1){
                entry += ".";
               // numOfDecs += 1;
               }
        }
        totaldiv.text(entry);
        testNumLength(entry);
    })
  
  $("#equals").click(function(){
    var result = eval(current + operator + entry);
    entry = result;
   
    totaldiv.html(result.toFixed(2));
    
    
  })
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To start chaining stuff you would need to support a more dynamic data structure than saving an operator and 2 numbers as their own fields.

You could have a single entry array that contains all numbers and operands submitted in order then loop through them to calculate (ignoring order of operations)

An array like that could look like the following with sample data:

```
[50, 'times', 25, 'plus', 10]
```

Then you could loop through it to determine the answer of the first operation (element 0, 1, 2 : 50x25) and then the next which is that answer plus 10, and so on.